# Matching a border of a russian word with \b

Tags: regex, perl, centos6.5, perl5.10

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong (when trying to match Russian swear words in a multiplayer game chat log) on CentOS 6.5 with the stock perl 5.10.1?

```
# echo блядь | perl -ne 'print if /\bбля/'

# echo блядь | perl -ne 'print if /бля/'
блядь

# echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Why doesn't the first command print anything?

Comment: What about `u` Unicode [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) `'print if /\bбля/u'` not familiar with perl, just a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately `/u` doesn't work: *Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/\bхуй/u"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell Perl that the source code contains UTF-8 (`use utf8`), and that the input (`-CI`) and output (`-CO`) are UTF-8 encoded:

```
echo 'помёт' | perl -CIO -ne 'use utf8; print if /\bпомё/'
```

Comment: Great answer! I am sysadmining several Russian servers and wondered for years, why my perl oneliners didn't work at the CLI

Comment: wondering why not `-CS` (with stderr too) e.g. `perl -Mutf8 -CS -ne` it is shorter :) :)